# How to get IConfiguration in Wolverine/Lamar ServiceRegistry

Tags: configuration, .net-8.0, lamar, wolverine

I am using Wolverine as my framework of choice. Wolverine comes with Lamar as IoC Container.
I have split my container registrations into ServiceRegistries. Now I need to access IConfiguration instance in those registries, but can't find a way to get it.

How to get the IConfiguration instance in ServiceRegistry subclasses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `IConfiguration` from `Program.cs` to your `ServiceRegistry`
like this:

Lets say you have your `ServiceRegistry`:

```
public class TestRegistry : Lamar.ServiceRegistry
{
    public TestRegistry(IConfiguration configuration) 
    {

    }
}
```

Then you pass `IConfiguration` from `Program.cs` like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// use Lamar as DI.
builder.Host.UseLamar((context, registry) =>
{
    // register services using Lamar

    registry.IncludeRegistry(new TestRegistry(context.Configuration));

});
```

`UseLamar()` is from `Lamar.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` NuGet package.

Comment: Ah, so there is no other way. :-(

Comment: @Luka not that I can think of :-/.